# Trying to set a property inside a UIView before awakeFromNib is called

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiview, awakefromnib

Im new to swift  - 
i have 2 viewcontrollers and a segue bitween them.
im trying to set a property inside the view before it is loaded. so this is some of the code from my uiview -

```
class ListUsersView: UIView {

  @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!  
  var dataSource: ListsUserDataSource?
  var nameForCellNib: String?

  override func awakeFromNib() {
      self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: nameForCellNib! , 
      bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: nameForCellNib!)
      ..
      ..
      ..
  }
```

Im having hard time setting nameForCellNib before the awakeFromNib (it is needed in awakeFromNib) thanks!

Comment: ok ill write some more. i tried to point to the problem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a `var` as soon as you have it, you can use it's `didSet` observer like so:

```
class ListUsersView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView! {
        didSet{
            tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: nameForCellNib!, bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: nameForCellNib!)
        }
    }
    .
    .
    . 

}
```